# How to print a message one time after all the iterations in the loop "for" are done?

Tags: c++, arrays

My program analyzes the array in the loop "for". If all elements satisfy the condition, it should print a message one time, but my program does it after each iteration.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int size = 32;
int ARR[size];

cout << "The size of the set is " << size << " elements." << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter the elements of the set: ";

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    cin >> ARR[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if (ARR[i] > ARR[i])
        cout << "\nThe relation is reflexive." << endl;
    else
        cout << "\nThe relation is not reflexive." << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I need that message to be printed after all the iterations are done. How can I achieve that result?

Comment: Maybe set a bool and check the bool after the loop.

Comment: You can use a variable like `isReflexive` to keep track of whether the condition has been violated yet. As soon as you see a case where the condition is `false`, you can set your flag to `false`, break out of the loop, and print the negative result. Otherwise, if you exit the loop without having found a counterexample, `isReflexive` will still be `true` and you can print the positive result. Either way, you'll make sure you only print _after_ you've reached a conclusion, instead of after each element you check.

Comment: `if (ARR[i] > ARR[i])`  this will never be true. The value of 1 element will not be greater than its same value. A smart compiler should replace the loop with something similar to `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << "\nThe relation is not reflexive." << endl;`

Comment: @drescherjm I know, but it must be so. It has no sense, but it's math.

Comment: @Alex _"... but it's math"_ Eeerm, then I'd suspect you misunderstood the formula.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  It's just a condition that always will be false. It's not the whole program.

Comment: @Alex _"It's just a condition that always will be false."_ So why doing that analysis at all then? If you know it's always false you can ditch the whole loop, and just do `cout << "\nThe relation is not reflexive." << endl;` _"It's not the whole program."_ Maybe your example is too much simplified.

Comment: I guess the idea is to replace `int` with something different later, which might be greater than itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy, just use a boolean flag to determine if the condition is met:

```
bool isReflexive = true;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (ARR[i] <= ARR[i]) {
        isReflexive = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(isReflexive)
    cout << "\nThe relation is reflexive." << endl;
else
    cout << "\nThe relation is not reflexive." << endl;
```

Note: The code above will always set `isReflexive` to false. You also need to compare two different indices:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    if (ARR[i-1] <= ARR[i]) { // Or whatever the correct comparison is
        isReflexive = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to separate analysis of "reflexiveness" from printing the result. That would allow you to simply end the loop as soon as negative result is determined:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    bool IsReflexive(int a[], int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i]) // TODO: correct this!!!
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    int main()
    {
        const int size = 32;
        int ARR[size];

        cout << "The size of the set is " << size << " elements." << endl << endl;
        cout << "Enter the elements of the set: ";

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cin >> ARR[i];
        }

        if (IsReflexive(ARR, size))
            cout << "\nThe relation is reflexive." << endl;
        else
            cout << "\nThe relation is not reflexive." << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```